# VB.NET Like operator confusion with less-than sign in pattern

Tags: vb.net, sql-like

```
Dim rc As Boolean = "2" Like "*?<*?"
```

I don't understand why rc equals True, surely `2` is not like `*?<*?` at all.

The above pattern requires a string with

- At least three characters (two ?'s and a `<`)
- where the `<` symbol is somewhere on the interior.

As far as I can work out `<` is not a special character that means something other than `<` to the Like operator.

Using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I don't know why "2" matches "<". However, it doesnt require three chars before since `*` is a wildcard for anything (so even zero chars).

Comment: I know * matches to anything, so "2" passes both the * and the ? wildcards, but the < is still missing from the match as is the second ?.

Comment: Curiously if you remove even one of the two ending wildcards the result is false.

Comment: "2" Like "`*?<" equals false. So does "2" Like "`*?<`*" So removing the final ? 'fixes' the issue.

Comment: Your question has at least `5` votes for the [tag:like-operator] tag. Could I kindly request that you suggest [tag:sql-like] as a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/like-operator/synonyms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't directly explain why `2` is like `"*?<*?"`.

Your query reads;

- `*` - Match 0 or more characters
- `?` - Followed by one single character
- `<` - Followed by the `<` character
- `*` - Followed by 0 or more characters
- `?` - Terminated by one single character

For your logic you want;

> at least three characters before it matches, with "<" occurring
>   somewhere on the interior of the string

Which results in a query of;

```
Dim rc As Boolean = "2" Like "???*<*"
```

Which reads;

- `???` - Match at least 3 characters
- `*`   - Followed by any number of further characters
- `<`   - Followed by the `<` character
- `*`   - Followed by any number of further characters

Not a direct answer I know, but I hope it helps all the same...

**EDIT:**

To answer your comment below.

You would like to;

> find a string which has a "<" in it somewhere with at least one character on either side

Which results in a query of;

```
Dim rc As Boolean = "2" Like "*?<?*"
```

This would return False as a result, as would;

```
Dim rc As Boolean = "<" Like "*?<?*"
```

However;

```
Dim rc As Boolean = "2<2" Like "*?<?*"
```

Would return true.

I hope this helps (more!)

Comment: What I need to do is find a string which has a "<" in it somewhere with at least one character on either side. I can write it easily enough using String.IndexOf and stuff, but I thought the Like operator would be an easy way out. I'll also need a match for a string with at least two < characters, with at least one character on either side of each < symbol (I thought *?<*?<*? would do it, but clearly I'm wrong).

Comment: Whoa, that works. WHYYYYY!? What's the logical difference between `?*` and `*?`

Comment: I think the compiler is getting confused, as `?*` means match at least 1 character then any number of further characters. Where as `*?` means match any number of characters, then 1 more. Which seems a bit strange when I say it out loud....